# Rails: Commands don't work inside format.json { .... }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm new to using ajax in rails and Im trying out `format.html` and `format.json` for the first time.

It all works fine submitting the data using ajax but for format.json it doesn't run the commands I want it to run on a successful submit.

```
 if @key.save
  format.html { 
     # Key update runs fine in format.html
    Key.find(@key.id).update(submitted_by: current_user.id)
  } 
 format.json {
      # Key update doesn't run in format.json
    Key.find(@key.id).update(submitted_by: current_user.id)
  }
else
 ....
```

Why doesn't the Key update command run in format.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create
  ......
  if @key.save
    Key.find(@key.id).update(submitted_by: current_user.id)
    respond_to |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json
    end
  else
  ..........
```

Comment: Sorry i was in auto pilot mode writing that coding. I updated my answer to what it looks like. And it doest work